# Segue Transition when using performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am doing using `performSegueWithIdentifier` to display a `UIView`.  I'd like for the transition to go from left to right, but it goes from right to left, no matter how I try and set it up.  Here is what I have right now:

```
function that calls the segue

    func settingsClick() {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SettingsSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Code inside of prepareForSegue

```
let vcSettings = segue.destinationViewController as SettingsController
let transitionType = CATransition()
transitionType.duration = 1.0
transitionType.type = kCATransitionPush
transitionType.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft

vcSettings.navigationController?.view.layer.addAnimation(transitionType, forKey: kCATransition)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Upon searching the internet, I find a lot of examples that use `pushViewController`, but I'm using `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Push/Show segue. This is a standard one, You shouldn't modify its animation, it's calling `pushViewController` behind the scene.

You have multiple options:

1. Create a custom segue.
2. Implement custom transition by looking at the navigation controller’s delegate which implements `‑navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:​fromViewController:toViewController:​`
3. Use Present Modally segue and implement a custom transition.

All the options have many resources online, you can google them.